# How do I keep the RDMS and Kafka in sync?

Tags: apache-kafka, cqrs, event-sourcing

We want to introduce a Kafka Event Bus which will contain some events like `EntityCreated` or `EntityModified` into our application so other parts of our system can consume from it. The main application uses an RDMS (i.e. postgres) under the hood to store the entities and their relationship.

Now the issue is how you make sure that you only send out `EntityCreated` events on Kafka if you successfully saved to the RDMS. If you don't make sure that this is the case, you end up with inconsistencies on the consumers.

I saw three solutions, of which none is convincing:

1. Don't care: Very dangerous, there can be something going wrong when inserting into an RDMS.
2. When saving the entity, also save the message which should be sent into a own table. Then have a separate process which consumes from this table and publishes to Kafka and after a success deleted from this table. This is quiet complex to implement and also looks like an anti-pattern.
3. Insert into the RDMS, keep the (SQL-) Transaction open until you wrote successfully to Kafka and only then commit. The problem is that you potentially keep the RDMS transaction open for some time. Don't know how big the problem is.
4. Do real CQRS which means that you don't save at all to the RDMS but construct the RDMS out of the Kafka queue. That seems like the ideal way but is difficult to retrofit to a service. Also there are problems with inconsistencies due to latencies.

I had difficulties finding good solutions on the internet.

Maybe this question is to broad, feel free to point me somewhere it fits better.

Comment: What is the source of truth for your application? The events or the Rdms?

Answer (score 2):

> When saving the entity, also save the message which should be sent into a own table. Then have a separate process which consumes from this table and publishes to Kafka and after a success deleted from this table. This is quiet complex to implement and also looks like an anti-pattern.

This is, in fact, the solution described by Udi Dahan in his talk: Reliable [Messaging without Distributed Transactions](https://vimeo.com/111998645).  It's actually pretty close to a "best practice"; so it may be worth exploring why you think it is an anti-pattern.

> Do real CQRS which means that you don't save at all to the RDMS but construct the RDMS out of the Kafka queue.

Noooo!  That's where the monster is hiding!  (see below).

If you were doing "real CQRS", your primary use case would be that your writers make events durable in your book of record, and the consumers would periodically poll for updates.  Think "Atom Feed", with the additional constraint that the entries, and the order of entries, is immutable; you can share events, and pages of events; cache invalidation isn't a concern because, since the state doesn't change, the event representations are valid "forever".

This also has the benefit that your consumers don't need to worry about message ordering; the consumers are reading *documents* of well ordered events with pointers to the prior and subsequent documents.

Furthermore, you've additionally gotten a solution to a versioning story: rather than broadcasting N different representations of the same event, you send out one representation, and then negotiate the content when the consumer polls you.

Now, polling does have latency issues; you can reduce the latency by broadcasting an announcement of the update, and notifying the consumers that new events are available.

If you want to reduce the rate of false polling (waking up a consumer for an event that they don't care about), then you can start adding more information into the notification, so that the consumer can judge whether to pull an update.

Notice that "wake up and maybe poll" is a process that is triggered by a single event in isolation.  "Wake up and poll just this message" is another variation on the same idea.  We broadcast a thin version of EmailDeliveryScheduled; and the service responsible for that calls back to ask for the email/an enhanced version of the event with the details needed to construct the email.

These are specializations of "wake up and consume the notification".  If you have a use case where you can't afford the additional latency required to poll, you can use the state in the representation of the isolated event.

But trying to reproduce an ordered sequence of events when that information is already exposed as a sharable, cacheable document... That's a pretty unusual use case right there.  I wouldn't worry about it as a general problem to solve -- my guess is that these cases are rare, and not easily generalized.

Note that all of the above is about *messaging*, not about *Kafka*.  Notice that messaging and event sourcing are documented as different [use cases](https://kafka.apache.org/uses).  [Jay Kreps](https://engineering.linkedin.com/distributed-systems/log-what-every-software-engineer-should-know-about-real-time-datas-unifying) wrote (2013)

> I use the term "log" here instead of "messaging system" or "pub sub" because it is a lot more specific about semantics and a much closer description of what you need in a practical implementation to support data replication.
>
> You can think of the log as acting as a kind of messaging system with durability guarantees and strong ordering semantics

The book of record should be the sole authority for the order of event messages.  Any consumer that cares about order should be reading ordered documents from the book of record, rather than reading unordered documents and reconstructing the order.

In your current design....

> Now the issue is how you make sure that you only send out EntityCreated events on Kafka if you successfully saved to the RDMS.

If the RDBMS is the book of record (the source of "truth"), then the Kafka log isn't (yet).

You can get there from here, over a number of gentle steps; roughly, you add events into the existing database, you read from the existing database to write into kafka's log; you use kafka's log as a (time delayed) source of truth to build a replica of the existing RDBMS, you migrate your read use cases to the replica, you migrate your write use cases to kafka, and you decommission the legacy database.

Kafka's log may or may not be the book of record you want.  [Greg Young](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDW0QWie21s) has been developing [Get Event Store](https://geteventstore.com/) for quite some time, and [has enumerated some of the tradeoffs](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/event-store/vb969DcTt5s/discussion) (2016).  Horses for courses - I wouldn't expect it to be too difficult to switch the *log* from one of these to the other with a well written code base, but I can't speak at all to the additional coupling that might occur.

Answer (score 1):

There is no perfect way to do this if your requirement is look SQL & kafka as a single node. So the question should be: "What bad things(power failure, hardware failure) I can afford if it happen? What the changes(programming, architecture) I can take if it must apply to my applications?"

For those points you mentioned:

2. What if the node fail after insert to kafka before delete from sql?
3. What if the node fail after insert to kafka before commit the sql transaction?
4. What if the node fail after insert to sql before commit the kafka offset?

All of them will facing the risk of data inconsistency(4 is slightly better if the data insert to sql can not success more than once such as they has a non database generated pk).

From the viewpoint of changes, 3 is smallest, however, it will decrease sql throughput. 4 is biggest due to your business logic model will facing two kinds of database when you coding(write to kafka by a data encoder, read from sql by sql sentence), it has more coupling than others.

So the choice is depend on what your business is. There is no generic way.